# Using Circle CI for Databricks

Tags: databricks, circleci, cicd

I have to use circleCI to deploy jobs in Databricks. So far I have scoured the internet trying to find a piece of information about it, Couldn’t find any. Can anyone help me with this please!?

Answer (score 1):

It's really a very broad question - you need to clarify what pieces need to be deployed, etc.

Databricks has a number of integrations described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/ci-cd/ci-cd-jenkins) & also in a number of blog posts like [this](https://databricks.com/blog/2021/09/20/part-1-implementing-ci-cd-on-databricks-using-databricks-notebooks-and-azure-devops.html) - you just need to adapt the described code to CircleCI-specific syntax - the overall structure is the same.

Usually, all integration is done either [Databricks REST API](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/index.html) or using [databricks-cli](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/cli/index.html) that allows to upload notebooks, create/update or trigger jobs, etc.

Specifically for CI/CD purposes you can look onto [dbx project](https://dbx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), especially to [dbx init](https://dbx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templates/python_basic.html) command that generates a skeleton of a project pre-configured for different CI/CD systems - it doesn't have CircleCI in the list, but it could be easily adapted.